# How to create grid table view in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datagridview, ios6

Hello I want to create a table view like as following image

[image: Sample Table View]

There is any library is available. how can create like this.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this repository [GridTableView](https://github.com/scasserly/GridTableView). 
I used the same code to create 10 columns in iPad application.
 Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: is it possible to set header for the particular column?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [**UICollectionView**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177)  and [**PSTCollectionView**](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)

or

You can use the **UITableView** for this and with your **own custom cell** which it is not complicated.

Note:

UICollectionView is only Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts. Collection views support customizable layouts that can be used to implement multi-column grids, tiled layouts, circular layouts, and many more. You can even change the layout of a collection view dynamically if you want.

Comment: Could you please provide simple example of how to create grid table?